# Consulta avanzada con Relationships en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, web, orm

Buenas, basicamente lo que deseo generar es una consulta que me devuelva una lista de usuarios, que tengan como valor excacto el resultado de la diferencia de dos campos.

Es decir tengo la tabla usuarios que tiene los campos ndias y diasconsumidos.

ACTUALMENTE estoy realizando lo siguiente

```
User::where('ndias','-','diasconsumidoss','=','5')->get();
```

pero esto no funciona.

Lo que quiero que haga es básicamente lo siguiente. Dejo el ejemplo de como debe quedar la consulta SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (users.ndias - users.diasconsumidos) =5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor en este caso sería utilizar `whereRaw`. El código sería así:

```
User::whereRaw('(ndias - diasconsumidos) = 5')->get();
```

Además, si quieres puedes pasar el valor `5` como parámetro de esta manera:

```
$myVar = 5;
User::whereRaw('(ndias - diasconsumidos) = ?', [$myVar])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar **[whereRaw](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereRaw)**

```
User::whereRaw('(users.ndias - users.diasconsumidos) =5')->get()
```